# Single files permission error (cannot modify/delete)

Tags: permissions, security

When I try to modify or delete a file on a subsite I get the "This control is currently disabled" error on the ribbon, and "this item is no longer available" if I try to click on the dropdown-triangle next to the item name.

This occurs even on the administrator account, and the account has full rights to the document library the item is in.

Strange thing is, this library is also showing as a webpart on the top level site and clicking on the dropdown-triangle there *does* let me modify and delete the file.

Any clues? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried this [Blog](http://girishm.blog.com/2010/07/11/this-item-is-no-longer-available-it-may-have-been-deleted-by-another-user-click-ok-to-refresh-the-page/) solution yet, it says that it could be your,

> ListViewWebPart is corrupted for pages library

and you might have to,

> Insert a new XSLTListViewWebPart for the desired library and save the
>   page.